# angular7 aot: Expression form not supported

Tags: angular, typescript, aot

In Angular7 I would like to create a util class like this:

```
export class FieldNameUtils {

  static toHump(name: string) {
    return name.replace(/_(\w)/g, function (all, letter) {
      return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
  }

  static toLine(name: string) {
    return name.replace('/([A-Z])/g', '_$1').toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

It's working well with development mode, but when I build with production, I got error like this:

```
field.name.utils.ts:4:25: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Expression form not supported.
  {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Expression form not supported","line":3,"character":24}
```

I have tried to change the `/_(\w)/g` to a static variable, but still got error, I know lambda expression is not supported, so I'v already change `(all, letter) => ...` to a `function(all, letter){ ... }`
The error shows that an expression after `replace(` is not supported, but it is a `RegExp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting up your regex as follows?

```
const regex = new RegExp('_(\w)', 'g');
```

Comment: thanks, the build process got stuck at 12% after I change to `new RegExp(...)` for quite a long time, I have to stop it manually

Answer (score 1):

Try to mark the class as

```html
// @dynamic
export class YourUtilClass {
}
```

I've encountered this problem during working with angular libraries.

Comment: I've been missing this. Thanks.